# Limit scope of an apache vhost .conf alias

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf, virtualhost

We have a vhost conf file which is a catch-all in a multi-tenant scenario, however there's a requirement for one of our clients to have a specific `alias` declaration which is currently defined like so...

```
Alias /special "/srv/application/public/example/special"
```

Currently this means that EVERY single client / domain in the system would be caught and forced to serve `/special/` which is obviously a problem.

**How can I limit the scope of this `Alias` declaration so that it is only applied when the requested domain matches `example.com` or `www.example.com`?**

FYI, we're moving from Apache 2.2 to 2.4 shortly, if there are any differences in the particular case, please point them out.  Thanks!

---

**EDIT** I should point out we're limited in this instance by middle ware and must keep everything in a single vhost declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to create a separate, non-default virtual host declaration just for that domain:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  Alias /special "/srv/application/public/example/special"
  # other default directives
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # other default directives
</VirtualHost>
```

The only disadvantage is that you'll then need to maintain the same `# other default directives` in both the example.com and default virtual hosts.  A good way to do that is to put them all into a file, and `Include` that file in both virtual host declarations.

Alternatively, you can keep just one virtual host declaration and add a RewriteRule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/special(/.*|$) /srv/application/public/example/special$1
```

Be sure to consider which method will be more sustainable when you add more exceptions in the future, as you surely will.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a large vhost file due to the multi-tenant nature, it sucks that we have to support this at all, but the hope is that this is only temporary.  I was thinking there might be a `<Directory...` or `RewriteCond` type solution, any thoughts?  The include is a good idea, unfortunately we're limited by middleware and need to keep things in one declaration.

Comment: @oucil: Added a RewriteRule solution.

Comment: Excellent!! Really appreciate that.  As far as sustainability, I know there's a performance hit here, it's an old client and we're just plugging a hole for now, but we'll be dumping the directive entirely in a few months. Problem solved :)  Again, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should put the alias directive within the VirtualHost definition for example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ...
    Alias /special /srv/application/pulic/example/special
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: As I pointed out in the question, this is a catch all for a multi-tenant app server, therefor `ServerName` is currently `localhost` and leaving the `Alias` in the overall vhost definition will mean every domain coming through that server would be affected.

Comment: My solution only works with example.com which is what you asked for.

Comment: I asked how I could limit the scope of the Alias, not how to redefine the entire vhost declaration.  I was guessing it would be a `<Directory...` or `RewriteCond` type solution.

Comment: You guessed wrong.

Comment: Other way around, take a look at accepted answer.

Comment: That is not limiting the scope of an alias which is what you asked for.

Comment: The rest of our community can continue to use `/special/` for their own purposes, but the redirection has been limited in scope to only that one clients domains.  It achieves the intent of my question exactly.

Answer (score -1):

large vhost files make managing very difficult, create an individual file for each tenant and INCLUDE it in the vhost file. this can be done live and have apache reload the configs when its done. this way you can support multiple domains per tenant and makes it easier to make changes like Andrew suggested above.

Comment: Really... you think I should load individual client data into each and every one of our application servers across our entire deployment, and then redeploy our app servers every time a new client signs on or adds a new domain, eh?

Comment: Sorry, but I am use to large deployments using a replicated file share for configs. Single place to make changes and fault tolerant due to replication. Apache can easily be reloaded and with staggered reloads, no down time. This also gets around your middle-ware issue.

Comment: These are two entirely different things, you're talking about replicated skeleton config / file system (as in Plesk) in a likely shared hosting environment where client configs are independent of each other and need to be variable.  This is not that. This is a multi-tenant SAAS deployment, SSL terminating load balancers, dozens of application servers, db cluster, dedicated service servers, multi-az failovers... and on and on and on.  It makes no sense whatsoever to roll out thousands of conf files to multiple load balancers just because I want to add one alias directive.

Comment: Apache was designed to have thousands of config files included into it. When it reaches an include statement it adds the contents of that included file to the main config in memory. From what I understand of your system, you are running many Apache systems in a load balance network. IF these are proxies, then no config is forwarded. just the requested website info, which should be cached for a period of time. If not used as proxies then have you considered using your SQL database to hold the configs and using a runtime script to get the configs into Apache?

Comment: I have dabbled with this sort of setup just to prove it works (on Apache2.2) but have not implemented it as the current included config files system is working without reason to change, yet.